# calculate the 100p-th percentile of Y

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Question:

Consider the pdf of the random variable Y
$f(y)$ = 
$
\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{25}, & 0 \le y \lt 5 \\
\frac{2}{5} - \frac{y}{25} & 5 \le y \lt 10
\end{cases}
$

calculate the 100p-th percentile of Y.

So the answer on my lecture notes is

$p$ = 
$
\begin{cases}
\frac{y^2}{50}, & 0 \le y \lt 5 \\
\frac{2}{5}y - \frac{y^2}{50} - 1 & 5 \le y \lt 10
\end{cases}
$

$y$ = 
$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{50p}, & p \le \frac{1}{2} \\
10 - \sqrt{50(1-p)} & p \gt \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$

I don't understand how to get $\sqrt{50p}$ and $10 - \sqrt{50(1-p)}$, how does y relate to p?

Comment: Hint: integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$PDF=f(y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{25}, & 0 \le y \lt 5 \\
\frac{2}{5} - \frac{y}{25} & 5 \le y \lt 10
\end{cases}\\
p=P(Y\le y)=\begin{cases}
\int_0^y f(y)dy=\int_0^y \frac y{25}dy=\frac{y^2}{50}, & 0 \le y \lt 5 \\
\int_0^5 \frac y{25}dy+\int_5^y f(y)dy=\frac12+\int_5^y \left(\frac25-\frac y{25}\right)dy=\frac{2}{5}y - \frac{y^2}{50} - 1, & 5 \le y \lt 10
\end{cases}$$
Also note that:
$$P(0\le Y<5)=\int_0^5 \frac y{25}dy=\frac{y^2}{50}\bigg{|}_0^5=\frac12 \Rightarrow p<\frac12 \iff 0\le y<5\\
P(5\le Y<10)=\int_0^{10} \frac 25-\frac y{25}dy=\left(\frac25y-\frac{y^2}{50}\right)\bigg{|}_5^{10}=\frac12 \Rightarrow p>\frac12 \iff 5\le y<10$$
Hence, for the given $p$:
$$0\le y<5 \Rightarrow p=\frac {y^2}{50} \Rightarrow y^2=50p \Rightarrow y=\sqrt{50}p\\
5\le y<10 \Rightarrow p=\frac{2}{5}y - \frac{y^2}{50} - 1 \Rightarrow y^2-20y+p+50=0 \Rightarrow y=10-\sqrt{50-p}$$
Note: $y=-\sqrt{50}p$ and $y=10+\sqrt{50-p}$ are rejected as $0\le y<10$.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly

- $f$ is the probability density function for $Y$.  It is $0$ for $y < 0$ and $y>10$
- $p$ is the cumulative density function for $Y$.  It is the integral of $f$ from $\-infty$ to $y$, and is $0$ for $y \lt 0$ but is $1$ for $y \gt 10$
- $y$ is the quantile function for $Y$.  It is effectively the inverse of $p$, so $y(p(y))=y$ and $p(y(p)) = p$ at least where these give unique values

So you could solve $p=\frac{y^2}{50}$ on $0 \le y \lt 5$ for $y$ to give $y =\pm \sqrt{50p}$ but the negative value clearly does not satisfy $0 \le y \lt 5$.  Similarly solving $y=\sqrt{50p}$ on $0 \lt p \lt \frac12$ gives $p=\frac{y^2}{50}$

You can do the same sort of thing with  $p=\frac{2}{5}y - \frac{y^2}{50} - 1$ on $5 \le y \lt 10$

As an example, consider $p(2)= \mathbb P(Y \le 2) =\int\limits_{-\infty}^2 f(y) \, dy = 0.08 = p(2)$. The inverse is $y(0.08)=2$.